# Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes in Jboss

Tags: java, spring, jboss, war

I'm getting a java.lang.SecurityException when trying to deploy a war in jboss but it is running fine on my machine.

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes
        at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.processImpl(SignatureFileVerifier.java:239) [:1.6.0_30]
        at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.process(SignatureFileVerifier.java:193) [:1.6.0_30]
        at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.processEntry(JarVerifier.java:296) [:1.6.0_30]
        at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.update(JarVerifier.java:207) [:1.6.0_30]
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.initializeVerifier(JarFile.java:342) [:1.6.0_30]
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.getInputStream(JarFile.java:410) [:1.6.0_30]
        at org.jboss.vfs.spi.JavaZipFileSystem.getFile(JavaZipFileSystem.java:159) [jboss-vfs.jar:3.0.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.getPhysicalFile(VirtualFile.java:262) [jboss-vfs.jar:3.0.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.web.deployers.AbstractWarDeployer$1.visit(AbstractWarDeployer.java:853) [:6.0.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.visit(VirtualFile.java:408) [jboss-vfs.jar:3.0.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.visit(VirtualFile.java:410) [jboss-vfs.jar:3.0.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.visit(VirtualFile.java:410) [jboss-vfs.jar:3.0.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.visit(VirtualFile.java:410) [jboss-vfs.jar:3.0.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.visit(VirtualFile.java:396) [jboss-vfs.jar:3.0.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.web.deployers.AbstractWarDeployer.getExplodedWarUrl(AbstractWarDeployer.java:866) [:6.0.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.web.deployers.AbstractWarDeployer.deploy(AbstractWarDeployer.java:400) [:6.0.0.Final]
        ... 47 more
```

Can any one explain me what might be causing it?

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is with your META-INF folder, i believe there are files in your META-INF folder of your jar or war which the jboss is trying to process those files or doesn't want it there.